# how can i send an email using node and sendgrid including a link?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am currently trying to use sendgrid within a node application to send an email which includes a link for email confirmation.  I am totally unsure as to how to achieve this and the docs aren't helping.  If anyone  knows how to do this please advise.
Current code:

```
const msg = {
      to: userObj.username,
      from: "email",
      subject: "dashboard account",
      text: `Hello, you have successfully created an account for the Dashboard`,
      html: "<a href='localhost:1337/'>Confirm Email<a/>"
    };
sgMail.send(msg).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The email is sent correctly, but just contains the words "Confirm Email" with no link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
html: `<a href='https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/send_emails/send_grid.js#L40'>This is Link<a/>`
```